# how do I get variables from one wx notebook page to a different wx notebook page?

Tags: python, wxpython

I am wondering how one would get a variable from one page to another from a wx notebook. I am thinking there should be some way to reference a variable if I know the variable name and page id. For example if I had the following code, how would I reference variable x from panel y and vice versa

```
import wx

class PanelX(wx.Panel):
    def __init__(self, parent):
        wx.Panel.__init__(self, parent)
        x = 3

class PanelY(wx.Panel):

    def __init__(self, parent):
        wx.Panel.__init__(self, parent)
        y=4

class MainFrame(wx.Frame):
    def __init__(self):
        wx.Frame.__init__(self, None, title="Main Frame", size = (500,450))

        p = wx.Panel(self)
        nb = wx.Notebook(p)

        nb.AddPage(PanelX(nb), "Panel X")
        nb.AddPage(PanelY(nb), "Panel Y")


        sizer = wx.BoxSizer()
        sizer.Add(nb, 1, wx.EXPAND)
        p.SetSizer(sizer)


if __name__ == "__main__":
    app = wx.App()
    MainFrame().Show()
    app.MainLoop()
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The variables you're creating in your panels aren't "saved" in the class - they're a local variable used in the constructor, and discarded from memory as soon as that method's executed.

You'll have to create your variables with "self" in front of them -- self.x = 3
This will create "instance variables" - variables that have different values depending on the class instance they belong to.

You can get a page from a Notebook by using its [GetPage](http://docs.wxwidgets.org/2.8/wx_wxnotebook.html#wxnotebookgetpage) method. Here's your example modified:

```
import wx

class PanelX(wx.Panel):
    def __init__(self, parent):
        wx.Panel.__init__(self, parent)
        self.x = 3

class PanelY(wx.Panel):

    def __init__(self, parent):
        wx.Panel.__init__(self, parent)
        self.y = 4

class MainFrame(wx.Frame):
    def __init__(self):
        wx.Frame.__init__(self, None, title="Main Frame", size = (500,450))

        p = wx.Panel(self)
        nb = wx.Notebook(p)

        nb.AddPage(PanelX(nb), "Panel X")
        nb.AddPage(PanelY(nb), "Panel Y")


        sizer = wx.BoxSizer()
        sizer.Add(nb, 1, wx.EXPAND)
        p.SetSizer(sizer)

        page = nb.GetPage(0)
        print "PanelX's X value is %s" % page.x

        page = nb.GetPage(1)
        print "PanelY's Y value is %s" % page.y       


if __name__ == "__main__":
    app = wx.App()
    MainFrame().Show()
    app.MainLoop()
```

Comment: +1 Thanks, the GetPage function was the missing link. Thanks for catching the local variables. That was on oversight.

Comment: no problem - I wasn't sure how detailed to go into describing local vs instance variables, plus I'm pretty rubbish at explaining those things :)

Comment: Is there an alternative to nb.GetPage that uses the string name of the page, or some other identifier besides an arbitrary integer?

Comment: I wouldn't say it's arbitrary - it's the order that the tabs are created in. What do you mean by name of the page? Page don't have names IIRC (been a few years since I've coded in wx though)